# How to find the value of the integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> > Find the value of the integral $$\int_C \frac {3z^5 - 10z^3} {z^6-5z^4+10}\ dz$$
> >
> > where $C = \left \{z \in \Bbb C\ :\ |z| < 2 \right \}.$

I know that $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz = \int_{a}^{b} f \left (\gamma (t) \right ) \gamma'(t)\ dt$$

where $\gamma : [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a piecewise continuous path (called a contour). By using this formula the given integral takes a weird form which I unable to simplify.

Would anybody please help me in this regard? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem Note also that your function has a special form: the numerator is the derivative of the denominator, divided by $2$. This is then the derivative of $\log(z^6 - 5z^4 + 10)$, so the calculation may be simplified further. Namely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: Can I diffrentiate $\log z$ over the entire $C$? I think no. Only it is differentiable in $C \setminus \{0 \leq z < \infty \}$ or $C \setminus \text {any half line}$.

Comment: You don't need $\log z$. It's a way to think about it: if you decompose $z^6 - 5z^4 + 10$ as $\prod (z - z_i)^{r_i}$, then its $\log$ becomes $\sum r_i\log(z - z_i)$ and taking derivative gives $\sum \frac{r_i}{z - z_i}$. Read the wiki page on argument principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are $4$ poles inside the region. Using Rouche's theorem, the denominator has the same number of zeros in $C$ as $-5z^4$:  $|z^6+10|\le|5z^4|=80$.

The residue at each pole is $p(z_k)/q'(z_k)=1/2$.

Thus by the residue theorem we get $2\pi i(4\cdot 1/2)=4\pi i$.

Comment: Calculator is not allowed inside examination hall.

Comment: How about Rouche's theorem?

Comment: Nice answer. +1. Many many thanks @Chris Custer.

Answer (score 1):

*First solution:* Computation using the definition, substitution $z=2e^{it}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J 
&:= \int_C \frac {3z^5 - 10z^3} {z^6-5z^4+10}\; dz
\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}
\frac 
{3\cdot 2^5 e^{5it} - 10\cdot 2^3e^{3it}} 
{2^6\cdot e^{6it}-5\cdot 2^4 e^{4it}+10}
\;2i\; e^{it}\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{2\pi}
\Big[\ 
\ln(\ 2^6\cdot e^{6it}-5\cdot 2^4 e^{4it}+10\ )\ 
\Big]'
\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\Big[\ 
\ln(\ 2^6\cdot e^{6it}-5\cdot 2^4 e^{4it}+10\ )\ 
\Big]_0^{2\pi}
\\
&=\dots
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let us take a look at a plot of the function under the logarithm:

[image: Plot of a parametric curve, closed contour]

It starts in $32-80+10=-38$, and maps the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ into

[image: Plot of a parametric curve, part of it]

then it closes the contour as in the picture on $[0,\pi]$, and then the corresponding even function $z^6-5z^4+10$ makes a new tour on it on $[\pi, 2\pi]$ using the parametrization $z=2e^{it}$. Taking logarithm, and computing the difference for the values in $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$ reveals the corresponding monodromy of the logarithm, we have to consier four times $2\pi i$. So the result is $\frac 12\cdot 8\pi i=4\pi i$.

*Second solution:* Residue computation.

First of all, let us locate all roots of the polynomial in the denominator, computer aided information:

```
sage: g = z^6 - 5*z^4 + 10
sage: roots = g.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=0)
sage: roots.sort()
sage: roots
[-2.123182227548205?,
 -1.325005689057003?,
 -1.124074217927793?*I,
 1.124074217927793?*I,
 1.325005689057003?,
 2.123182227548205?]
```

Let $a$ be a root under the above numbers inside the circle $C$. Then it is a pole of order one for the function under the integral, and the residue is
$$
\lim_{z\to a}
(z-a)\cdot
\frac {3z^5 - 10z^3} {z^6-5z^4+10} 
=
\lim_{z\to a}
\frac {3z^5 - 10z^3} {(z^6-5z^4+10)/(z-a)} 
=
\frac {3a^5 - 10a^3} {(z^6-5z^4+10)'_{\text{in }z=a} }
=\frac 12\ .
$$
There are four roots of the denominator inside the circle $C$, so by the residue theorem the value of the integral is
$$
2\pi i\left(
\frac 12+
\frac 12+
\frac 12+
\frac 12
\right)
=4\pi i\ .
$$

---

P.S. The answer was started last year... now i could complete and submit...

Comment: Thanks. Very nice informative answer. Wish you a very happy new year $2020.$